# PHP 8.1 Upgrade error: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array

Tags: php

I've found a few similar posts but am a complete novice with PHP so hoping someone can help.
After updating from PHP 7.4 to 8.1 I am getting the following error message;

PHP 8.1 Upgrade error: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array

I've traced to code which I think is causing the problem to

```
fputs($output, implode($row, ',')."\n");
```

Comment: Just read the docs - first argument in `implode()` is separator, second - array. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php

Comment: [implode depracated historical parameter order](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php#migration74.deprecated.core.implode-reverse-parameters), reverse the order of the arguments passed to it.

Comment: Thanks but how would I reverse the code? - sorry I'm a complete php novice :-(

Comment: Than not upgrade to php8.

Comment: @Mios `implode(',', $row)` instead of `implode($row, ',')`

Comment: Note that what you were told was "reverse the order of the parameters" not "reverse the code". Big difference.